# WTForms QuerySelectField - not a valid choice

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am using QuerySelectField in many pages in a Flask app and it is working fine.  Except in one route where I keep getting the message "not a valid choice" when I submit the form.

Yet, the dropdown menu is populated correctly and a choice is indeed selected in it.  When I print() the field data, I get a "None" so there seems to be the problem since even if we select a choice, the form seems to pass "None" as the result.  Any idea why?

The field is set as:

```
buy_pc = QuerySelectField('Punch-cards',query_factory=getPunchcards,get_label='label')
```

Here is the full form:

```
def getPunchcards():
    return Punchcard.query

class Add_participants(Form):
    member_name = StringField('Type the tribe\'s member full name:', validators=[DataRequired()])

    choice = RadioField('Registration mode',validators=[DataRequired()],choices=[('season_pass','Season Pass'),
                                                    ('punchcard', 'Punch-card'),
                                                    ('free_pass','Using a free pass'),
                                                    ('old_punchcard','Using old punch-card'),
                                                    ('dropin','Drop-in'),
                                                    ('checked','Use another member punch-card')])


    dropin_ammount = IntegerField('Drop-in ammount',validators=[NumberRange(min=0,max=25,message='Please '
                                                                              'enter an amount btw 0 and 25')],default=10)
    add_note = BooleanField('Add a note to the member profile')
    note_content = TextAreaField()
    other_punchcard = StringField('Type the tribe\'s member full name:')
    buy_pc = QuerySelectField('Punch-cards',query_factory=getPunchcards,get_label='label')
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really have a look at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for some code style guidelines (functions etc should be `snake_case` and class names should be `CamelCase`). Also, there's only one "m" in "amount"

Comment: What's the primary key of `Punchcard`?

Comment: The id column  
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

And thanks for the link.  I'm using this project to finally learn python + flask, so this is very useful